# How to trigger routeUpdate without changing the value of params in $location.search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my application I use `routeUpdate` to check if the `$location.search` string has changed and navigate accordingly in my view. 
Like so.

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(next, current) {        
    var slide_key = $location.search().slide_key;
    if (slide_key)
    $scope.go_to_slide(slide_key);      
});
```

Also keep in mind that I use `reloadOnSearch` false to not reload the controller.

Usually I trigger this by changing the `$location.search` and works fine

Everything works fine but there is a case where I want to **trigger this behavior without changing the search parameters**.

I tried to just change the search parameters to again the same value -> No luck.

If I change it to another value then the `routeUpdate` fires and everything works ok.

So how can I manually trigger the `routeUpdate` without changing value of params in `$location.search` ?

Comment: Could you put together a small jsfiddle for this please. It'll be easier to debug that way. Cheers

Comment: I think I have idea on how to achieve this but I need some of your code (the controller maybe?) so I can see how my idea fits into your code.

Comment: @dcodesmith Just finished work, gonna go home and by tomorrow you ll havee the code.

Comment: Hey, still waiting :)

Comment: @dcodesmith, I think he meant his next work day.. I trimmed down the route example for my testing http://jsfiddle.net/BXAM4/

Comment: @dcodesmith I was lokking for $emit. lossleader did it. I have difficulties creating the fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are right that you will have to manually interfere if you want to trigger a real `$routeUpdate` event without a url change that affects `$location.absUrl()`.

**This example triggers the $routeUpdate event:**

```
<a ng-click="$emit('$locationChangeSuccess','hiya')" href="">update route</a>
// or the precise broadcast would be:
// $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess',$location.absUrl(), $location.absUrl())
```

But in your current code you do nothing with the parameters from `$routeUpdate`, so you could also just broadcast a fake or alternate event for the `$routeUpdate`.

**Other alternatives that seem cleaner have reasons they can't work:**

`$route.reload()` always forces the real update path:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L352
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L415

`$location` is relying on comparisons to `$browser`'s url, so you can't really get it to fire off normally without changing a meaningful part of the url:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L560

Comment: Thank you. The $emit was what I was looking for. Should have done my homework better. Though I used $routeUpdate on the $emit and works fine. You example in the fiddle doesn't work for me. And fiddle is a service really difficult for me to use especially due to the change of interpolations and like the fix you have ;-)

Comment: Cool! But sorry the fiddle didn't work, jsfiddle seems to use separate paths for saved and edited runs, so you have to change something before running it. :) It looks like we can use *paths with a newer angular to get around it in future fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/BXAM4/6/